# How to map the type of MUI icons?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I currently have this:

```
type MenuItem = {
  key: string;
  order: number;
  text: string;
  icon: typeof SvgIcon;
};
```

But then Typescript complains when I try to:

```
      <List>
        {MENU.map((menuItem: MenuItem) => (
          <ListItem key={menuItem.key}>
            <ListItemButton>
              <ListItemIcon>{menuItem.icon}</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={menuItem.text}>
                {menuItem.text}
              </ListItemText>
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
```

It says this:

```
typescript: Type 'OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & { muiName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

So how do I narrow my MenuItem.icon attribute so it can only receive an icon from the icons librsary ofMUI?

Thank you

Comment: typeof SvgIcon is the type for the component itself (a function) rather than a instance of the component (a React element).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
      <List>
        {MENU.map((menuItem: MenuItem) => {
          const MenuItemIcon = menuItem.icon;
          return (
            <ListItem key={menuItem.key}>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                   <MenuItemIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={menuItem.text}>
                  {menuItem.text}
                </ListItemText>
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          )
        })}
      </List>
```

Comment: You need to move the `const MenuItemIcon` inside the loop.

Comment: Woops, yes sure. Here's a edited  version. thank you for the keen eye ️  @LindaPaiste